# How to test PhoneGap API's with browser or Adobe Build?

Tags: javascript, ios, file, cordova

Currently I am developing a PhoneGap application that I have been testing using the Ripple emulator in Chrome. I have also been using Adobe Build to send the app to my phone. Now I am interesting in testing out some of the PhoneGap API features such as File API or Camera API.

As an example, I found this FileSystem script that I'd really like to try out:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log("device is ready");
    window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem ||      window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function fail() {
    console.log("failed to get filesystem");
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    console.log("got filesystem");

        // save the file system for later access
    console.log(fileSystem.root.fullPath);
    window.rootFS = fileSystem.root;
}

function downloadImage(url, fileName){
    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.download(
        url,
        window.rootFS.fullPath + "/" + fileName,
        function(entry) {
            console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);

        },
        function(error) {
            console.log("download error" + error.code);
        }
    );
}
```

Without having much knowledge on how to test this outside of my browser or using Adobe Build, I was wondering what the best way/workflow would be to get this to work? I noticed there are console.log functions, so I tried it out in Chrome, but I get the error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: LocalFileSystem is not defined." I'm assuming I need to use an emulator of sorts?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: can you just run it on a spare smartphone? you can buy a $20 smartphone for development use over wifi. It's worth it because you can't really test touch interaction UX very well with a mouse...

Comment: I found this article(http://www.tricedesigns.com/2013/01/18/my-workflow-for-developing-phonegap-applications/) very helpful while developing a phonedap app. But, as @dandavis has said: The best way to test your mobile app is using a real phone.

Comment: Or just use an emulator. If you're on a mac you of course have the iOS emulator bundled with xcode. Otherwise, there's always the android emulator (though it's a bit slow if you're not using the intel port).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who runs into this question in the future. I took the route of running the iOS emulator alongside JSConsole (http://jsconsole.com/). JSConsole was a wonderful solution to allowing me to see my console.log reports while running the emulator. It essentially has you attach a js file to your html pages and it sends your console.log events remotely to the website, so that you can debug virtually!

Comment: Thanks for jsconsole. was looking for a nice tool to help me debug

Comment: No problem! Enjoy :)